# Which statistical model/test to use for understanding change in housing location?

Tags: multiple-regression, pca, spss, causality

I have data on 1000 households.
I have:

- Their present housing location and their previous house's location before they moved to this house (Latitude, Longitude)
- Count of urban amenities (spread across 53 categories) they can access if they drive 500m, 1km, 2km or 5km from their present house. (53X4 columns)
- Count of urban amenities (spread across 53 categories) they can access if they drive 500m, 1km, 2km or 5km from their previous house. (53X4 columns)
- Floor Area of present and previous house
- Rent of present and previous house
- Building Typology of previous and present house (1BHK/2BHK/3BHK/4BHK, BHK = Bedroom, hall, kitchen, so 1BHK has only 1 bedroom, 2BHK has 2 bedrooms and likewise)
- Present income of the household and past income of the household from the time they lived in their previous household
- Their travel-related data from the past and present, i.e. the mode of transport they used before vs. now.

What kind of statistical modelling will give me insights into the data? I need to determine causation. Why did these people move to their new houses.

Comment: [Latent transition analysis](https://www.methodology.psu.edu/ra/lta/) might be a good way to proceed to understand trends on movement. There is likely no way to understand the choices that caused each individual to move houses. That is an impossible task. But you can see which characteristics of the individual are associated with transition to different types of housing using LTA.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Noah mentioned, there's no way to establish a causal link between an individual and whether they moved or not.

This sounds like an interesting problem! Here's one approach. If you can group the latitude and longitude information of the present location into regions, you could try and predict that (see [multinomial regression](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/multinomial-logistic-regression-using-spss-statistics.php)). If you include the past location as a predictor (along with the other variables, which could also be summarised at a regional level) then you can use a multinomial regression to determine the likelihood of moving to the current location. You can then inspect the model coefficients to see what's potentially driving the probability of moving to that location.